# How and can I use webpack aliases in Storybook after building prod build and installing it in my app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, storybook

Here is the thing.

When I'm using aliases in storybook like this it works fine. IDE is able to resolve the path, giving me suggestions etc.

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { IButtonProps } from 'src/Buttons/Button';
export interface IModalProps extends IButtonProps {
```

When I run webpack5 to build production build it builds fine, zero errors etc.
But when I install my package in some app and try to use, for example, Modal component from it that has imports with aliases, IDE highlights line with

```
import { IButtonProps } from 'src/Buttons/Button';
```

and says *TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/Buttons/Button' or its corresponding type declarations.*

It happens only after installing package in some app in node_modules.
I'm no longer able to use aliases and types from *IButtonProps* interface, it's unreachable.

My webpack.config.js has config for alias

```
alias: {
      src: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src'),
    },
```